# IAM Role not showing in aws console in Modify IAM role page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, user-roles

I created an IAM role using the aws console and attached AmazonS3FullAccess policy. When I spun up an ec2 instance and tried to attach the profile, the profile  does not show up in the list of available profile.

I have the following permissions:

```
"iam:PassRole",
"iam:ListInstanceProfiles"
```

What permissions do I need to list the profiles? Not sure what is missing, any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need the following as the Trust Relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```