# IAM Role does not show in role list of EC2, even though I have the trust relationship set up correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-roles

I have the following demo role created for AWS:

[image: Demo Role Summary]

with the following trust relationship:

[image: Demo Role Trust Relationships]

Now, I am trying to modify the role of an EC2 instance to be `DemoRoleForEC2`, but the role is not appearing in the dropdown list:

[image: Modify IAM Role Page]

According to this answer here: [IAM Role not showing in aws console in Modify IAM role page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168577/iam-role-not-showing-in-aws-console-in-modify-iam-role-page) , it should be working fine as the Trust Relationships are ok, but it is not.

Other things I tried was stopping and restarting the EC2 Instance, and trying to create the role from the "Modify Role for IAM" page, but none worked. Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Could AWS console issue. Have you tried using AWS CLI for that?

Comment: Did you create the role from AWS Console or CLI? To attach the role to an instance you need additionally an Instance Profile. When creating via AWS Console it happens behind the scenes (created together with IAM Role) but if you are creating via CLI then you need to explicitly create it apart from IAM Role

Comment: I am new to AWS, following a course on Udemy, and am running into an identical issue. In my case both instance and role were created from the AWS Console.

Comment: I'm following the exact same udemy course and had this issue. I created the role from the console, but haven't tried to set it from the CLI

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Role can be used by an EC2 instance only if it has an associated Instance Profile, as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html

When creating a role using the web console, you need to specify at the start that it will be used for an EC2 instance. In this case the Instance Profile is created automatically, with the same name as a role.

If the Role cannot be assigned to an EC2 instance, you can create an Instance Profile manually, for example:

```bash
aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name MyRoleInstanceProfile
aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --role-name MyRole --instance-profile-name MyRoleInstanceProfile
```

And then the role will appear in the list in the "Modify Role for IAM" page.

Another option is to simply recreate the Role the proper way and specify in the wizard that it's for an EC2 instance.

Comment: I ran into the same issue a while ago. Not only I had to create a new instance profile with new role as mentioned above but also had to replace the existing ec2 instance profile using 

`aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --instance-id <ec2-instance-id> --iam-instance-profile Name=MyRoleInstanceProfile
aws ec2 replace-iam-instance-profile-association --association-id <existing-association-id> --iam-instance-profile Name=MyRoleInstanceProfile`

Existing association details can be retrieved using 
`aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations --region <region>`

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is the browser you are using to do this task and any browser extensions you may have installed.

I hit this issue where I was creating an EC2 role via the AWS console but it was not creating the instance profile.

I found the issue to be because I was using chrome and with the ClearURLs extension. I disabled this extension and when I then tried to create the role via the console, then the instance profile was also being created.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was creating an instance profile and adding a role with the CLI. Then, the instance profile was not showing up on EMR but it was appearing on EC2. After several attempts I tried naming the instance profile and the role with the same name (and no special characters), and then it worked.